# Save controllers objects for different model

Tags: php, oop, laravel, laravel-4

I'm beginning at using a PHP framework like Laravel or CodeIgniter. And i think i understood the basic.

Here is my example.

Admit that, after an auth user, we go to:

```
mysite.fr/username/
```

And then i load all the books that this user wrote from my database.

```
so the username/index controllers call the books models.
```

Then the user can click on a filter button to display only the books for KIDS so the URI will be :

```
mysite.fr/username/books/kids
```

Here, the books model will make a new query to find all the books where categories = "KIDS"

Which i think is bad because we already load all the books before ! So we don't need to make a new query but only apply filter on the Books object !

Is there anyway to save a model in the controller and then access it from DIFFERENT controllers without have to recreate the whole object ?

What i would like to do is :

```
username/index
    Books already loaded ? call the view with Book object : make the query
username/books/categories
    Books already loaded ? call the view for categories : make the query for this categories
```

May be that's not at all in the spirit of OOP but why go quering for infos that we already have ??

The only way i see to make that is to save the model in a file...but not really efficient.

Thanks a lot for your help and excuse my english, not my primary language...

Comment: You loaded all the books in the first request, but (unless you use some form of caching) they are unloaded when the script terminates... so "Books already loaded" is meaningless... this isn't as inefficient as you seem to think, it's worked pretty well for millions of PHP websites so far without causing problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In laravel you can just cache the results: `Cache::put($key, $value), Cache::get($key).` Or alternatively you can use query caching by just chaining the `->remember()` method on the end of your query.

Checkout [Caching](http://laravel.com/docs/cache)
Checkout [Query caching](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#caching-queries)

Comment: Yes, as @MarkBaker suggested it and so you, i'll look at this functionnality. Thanks.